# Load URL use iframe on HTML5 of PhoneGap Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

I want to load the entire contents of a web page on my HTML page. I use ***iframe*** to do this. I test on android 2.3 is normal. But when tested on android 4.0 or higher, that does not load the site anymore and instead white screen. I use PhoneGap cordova to do this. I'm using 2.8.1 cordova.

My Code file index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>com.PhoneGap.c2dm</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="GCMPlugin.js"></script> <!-- GCM Cordova plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_1.5.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include my Javascript routines -->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="GCMPlugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="CORDOVA_GCM_script.js"></script>  -->

</head>
 <body>
<iframe src="http://m.kqxs.vn"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would reconsider some other way of getting what u want instead of iframe